# How can I go about solving this proof of a version of L'Hopital Rule?

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $g : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ are differentiable functions. Suppose at $c \in (a,b)$, $f(c) = g(c) = 0, g'(x) \neq 0$ when $x \neq c, $ and that $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$  exists. Prove that $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$

Honestly I'm not very sure how to begin with this proof. Can someone give me help?

Comment: Mean value theorem?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} & = \lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x) - 0}{g(x) - 0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{g(x) - g(c)}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\rightarrow c}\left[\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c}\right]\left[\frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x - c}\right]^{-1} = \ldots
\end{align*}

Comment: and so the first term of the last part is just the definition of f'(x), the second term is 1/g'(x), as we take lim x goes to c, and then it equals the right hand side which is lim as x goes to c of f'(x)/g'(x). Is that it? If so thanks! That's a clever substitution.